# Detect when map camera begins moving

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Is there any way to detect when a GoogleMaps map begins moving / begins camera change when the change is *not* initiated by user input?

I know I can tap into the touch events for when a user manually moves it, but I can't find where to tap into any event that is triggered programmatically.

So if I call something like this

```
_nativeMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(newCameraLocation), _animationDuration, null);
```

The only event that I see raised is `CameraChange` which only happens after the change is complete.

I really need some way to detect when it begins moving.

*note: this example is Xamarin / C# but I don't really care about that.*

Comment: What initiates the movement of the camera in your case?

Comment: The code snippet above uses `AnimateCamera`. I wanted to try inheriting from `GoogleMap` and overriding the AnimateCamera method to include another event, but it's sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is efficient. But maybe you can use a handler to check each x seconds if the maps is still centered at the same position.

Lets say you have

```
LatLng lastPosition;
```

Use a handler like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = REFRESH_RATE;

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        LatLng newPosition = mapView.getCameraPosition().target;
        double distance = computeDistance(newPosition, lastPosition);
        if(distance > THRESHOLD)
            //Camera moved.
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Now you need to define the refresh rate, and the minimum distance to conclude that you have a movement. You need to find a way to compute distances too, Location has a built-in method...

You can use this handler after animateCamera() and cancel it on Animation onFinish().

Comment: ah, yes. Precisely what I've been experimenting with.

Comment: yeah, this seems to be the only way.